Struggling to position objects correctly in Manim
My end goal with this program is to simulate constrained pendulums with springs but that is a goal for later, currently I have been trying to learn how object creation, positioning and interactions would work and will eventually build the way up.
Currently I have been trying to make my code produce N number of independent pendulums side by side but they all spawn at the same position.
I have tried a lot of things from trying to define a method to create multiple pendulums at once to the current iteration where I try to use a for loop for creating and shifting the position of the pendulum but to no avail.
import numpy as np
import manim as mn

class Pendulum:
    def __init__(self, mass, length, theta):
        self.mass = mass
        self.length = length
        self.g = -9.81
        self.angle = theta
        self.angular_vel = 0

    def step(self, dt):
        # Defining RK4
        def runge_kutta_4(f, t, y0, h=None):
            if h is None:
                h = t[1] - t[0]
            n = len(t)
            y = np.zeros((n, len(y0)))
            y[0] = y0
            for i in range(n - 1):
                k1 = h * f(t[i], y[i])
                k2 = h * f(t[i] + h/2, y[i] + k1/2)
                k3 = h * f(t[i] + h/2, y[i] + k2/2)
                k4 = h * f(t[i] + h, y[i] + k3)
                y[i+1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6
            return y

        def pendulum_equations(t, state):
            theta, omega = state
            force = self.mass * self.g * np.sin(theta)
            torque = force * self.length
            MoI = 1/3 * self.mass * self.length**2
            alpha = torque / MoI
            return np.array([omega, alpha])

        state = np.array([self.angle, self.angular_vel])
        t = np.array([0, dt])
        sol = runge_kutta_4(pendulum_equations, t, state)
        self.angle = sol[-1, 0]
        self.angular_vel = sol[-1, 1]

class PhysicalPendulum(mn.Scene):
    def construct(self):
        p = Pendulum(2, 10, np.pi/2)
        N = 3 # change number of pendulums here
        pendulums = []
        scale = 0.5
        spacing = 3 # Adjust the spacing between pendulums as needed

        def get_pendulum(i, rod_width=0.2, rod_height=1):
            rod = mn.Rectangle(width=rod_width, height=scale * p.length, color=mn.BLUE)
            rod.shift(mn.DOWN * scale * p.length / 2)
            rod.rotate(p.angle, about_point=rod.get_top())
            pendulum = mn.VGroup(rod)
            pendulum.shift(mn.UP * 3) # Adjust the vertical shift as needed
            if i % 2 == 0:
                pendulum.shift(mn.RIGHT * spacing * i)
            else:
                pendulum.shift(mn.LEFT * spacing * i)
            return pendulum

        def step(pendulum, dt, i):
            p.step(dt)
            pendulum.become(get_pendulum(i))

        for i in range(N):
            pendulum = get_pendulum(i)
            pendulum.add_updater(lambda mob, dt: step(mob, dt, i))
            pendulums.append(pendulum)

        self.add(*pendulums)
        self.wait(20)

        for pendulum in pendulums:
            pendulum.remove_updater(step)

Also this is my first time trying Object Oriented Programming so I would appreciate any tips on how to improve the coding style and any comments on things I have been doing wrong.

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

This is a classical example of a good question. You were almost complete in your code. I made a few change to it, and as I was doing this in google.colab, there might be some things that you'll need to add,
import numpy as np
import manim as mn

class Pendulum:
    g = -9.81  

    def __init__(self, mass, length, theta):
        self.mass = mass
        self.length = length
        self.angle = theta
        self.angular_vel = 0

    def step(self, dt):
        def runge_kutta_4(f, t, y0, h=None):
            if h is None:
                h = t[1] - t[0]
            n = len(t)
            y = np.zeros((n, len(y0)))
            y[0] = y0
            for i in range(n - 1):
                k1 = h * f(t[i], y[i])
                k2 = h * f(t[i] + h/2, y[i] + k1/2)
                k3 = h * f(t[i] + h/2, y[i] + k2/2)
                k4 = h * f(t[i] + h, y[i] + k3)
                y[i+1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6
            return y

        def pendulum_equations(t, state):
            theta, omega = state
            force = self.mass * self.g * np.sin(theta)
            torque = force * self.length
            moment_of_inertia = 1/3 * self.mass * self.length**2
            alpha = torque / moment_of_inertia
            return np.array([omega, alpha])

        state = np.array([self.angle, self.angular_vel])
        t = np.array([0, dt])
        sol = runge_kutta_4(pendulum_equations, t, state)
        self.angle = sol[-1, 0]
        self.angular_vel = sol[-1, 1]

class PhysicalPendulum(mn.Scene):
    def construct(self):
        N = 3  
        pendulums = [Pendulum(2, 10, np.pi/2) for _ in range(N)]
        scale = 0.5
        spacing = 3  
        def get_pendulum(pendulum, i, rod_width=0.2, rod_height=1):
            rod = mn.Rectangle(width=rod_width, height=scale * pendulum.length, color=mn.BLUE)
            rod.shift(mn.DOWN * scale * pendulum.length / 2)
            rod.rotate(pendulum.angle, about_point=rod.get_top())
            pendulum_group = mn.VGroup(rod)
            pendulum_group.shift(mn.UP * 3)  
            pendulum_group.shift(mn.RIGHT * spacing * i) 
            return pendulum_group

        def step(pendulum, dt, i):
            pendulums[i].step(dt)
            pendulum.become(get_pendulum(pendulums[i], i))

        pendulum_groups = []
        for i in range(N):
            pendulum_group = get_pendulum(pendulums[i], i)
            pendulum_group.add_updater(lambda mob, dt, i=i: step(mob, dt, i))  
            pendulum_groups.append(pendulum_group)

        self.add(*pendulum_groups)
        self.wait(20)

        for pendulum_group in pendulum_groups:
            pendulum_group.remove_updater(step)


To run it in colab, if you do, you'll have to do a few things. It is rather tricky to install manin there. You need to do this:
!pip install manim
!apt-get install texlive texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-extra texlive-latex-recommended texlive-science dvipng
!apt-get install ffmpeg
!apt-get install sox
!apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev

!pip install manim



To run the code:
%load_ext manim

and
%%manim -ql -v WARNING PhysicalPendulum


Here is a snapshot:

